# server event of dropdown is not fired

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist, in the client side, i have it's on change event. If validation is passed, it's selected inded changed event should be fired(server side).  My side, the server event is not getting fired.  Autopostback is also set is true.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you returning true / false from your client side event?

Comment: yes, despite of sending true from client side, not going to server side.

Comment: If you look in the Modules window of visual studio while the site is running, do you have the correct location and pdb file loaded for the web app assembly? I have had similar issues before that were resolved by deleting the bin and obj directories from the web app so it does a full recompile

Comment: How does the dropdown get added to the page?  Is it in the ASPX/ASCX markup,or are you dynamically adding it from the code-behind?

Comment: Do you have it in updatepanel? Please post code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding the code from the code-behind (as opposed to in the ASPX or ASCX markup), make sure you add it in the Page_Init event or override CreateChildControls.  If you want until the Page_Load event to add it, the ASP.NET has already initialized the control state and view state and then will not be aware that the dropdown exists, so when the postback comes it won't know what control to route it to.

Also, in this case, make sure you are always adding the control to the page, not just when Page.IsPostback==false

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page code is in autoeventwireup = true.

you can check it in your page design page on top.

if autoeventwireup is set to false your event doesn't fire. auto event will set automatically event so it is necessary to write else you have to set event on initialize state.